# React Native Webview - How to add customized styles for specific html elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I have a react native app that uses webview to render html elements. The problem is I wanted to add customized style for some images.

Here's the example of html contents. The content comes from the backend.

```
const htmlElements = '<div><a><img src="https://image1.png" /><img src="https://image2.png" /><img src="https://image3.png"/></a><a><img src="https://image4.png" /><img src="https://image5.png" /><img src="https://image6.png" /></a></div>'
```

And here's how I used it in React Native

```
   const renderHtml = () => {
      return (
        '<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">' +
        htmlElements +
        '</div>'
      );
    };
```

Is it possible to add styles based on the `src` name.

Like for example if the image src is equals to `image6.png` then I'll modify the styles such as `margin-left: 30px;`